# Refresh all tabs in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser, browser-addons

I am using Google Chrome 11.0.696.77 on Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

Is it possible to refresh(reload) all the tabs in Google Chrome without going into each individual tab and hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh the page?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's an extension that does exactly that:

#### [Reload All Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/midkcinmplflbiflboepnahkboeonkam)

Features:

- Keyboard shortcut to reload tabs is bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>
- Reload all tabs in all windows (enabled via options)
- Option to just reload pinned tabs
- Configurable keyboard shortcut
- Configurable context menu

It also sits in the toolbar so you could just click a button.

Comment: It seems you have to use combination of Ctrl+shift+R plus selecting All tabs.

Comment: still works in Windows 10...good, but it's ALT + Shift + R

Comment: Bad extension :( When you open tabs "today" is can reloads them. But after couple of days it reload 30% of opened tabs or less. After a week of working (without browser closing) it does not reload any tabs at all!

Answer (score 64):

You can select multiple tabs by holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (in OS X: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>) and clicking on multiple tabs. If you want to select all of the tabs click on the first tab, hold down <kbd>shift</kbd>, then click on the last tab.

Now that you've selected the tabs, right click on any of the tabs and click reload.

Comment: Simple and effective.

Comment: Wow, you can do that?  That's great! (except for the fact that I've been missing out for so long...) No need to install anything, you can quickly select any arbitrary group of tabs, and works for dragging around, closing, pinning, silencing or duplicating, besides reloading!  This will come real handy while using The Great Suspender to keep any number of tabs open without them eating all the RAM...

Comment: Great solution! Click on first tab, hold down Shift, then click on last tab, F5, done!

Comment: This is the much better answer, rather than installing an extension.

Comment: Wow, this is incredible, especially all the uses Chema pointed out.  I've always done these things manually!  Wow!

Answer (score 6):

Another method without installing extensions: set Chrome to reopen the pages that were open last in Options, then close and reopen the browser. Occasionally I'll do this to refresh all the pages if I accidentally open my browser without an internet connection :-)

Answer (score 6):

1. You should select all relevant tabs by pressing the first tab and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and clicking on the last tab. Or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+  and clicking on any tab you wish to reload.
2. After all relevant tabs are selected: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: I tried many of the above-mentioned solutions, but this one was the only that worked for me (Windows 10, Google Chrome)!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into something called iMacros(extension for chrome). I know it is in its early stages for Chrome, but things like that could be easily recorded and then at the click of a button the script would go through and hit refresh.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like those shortcuts and select multiple tabs are gone in Windows 10.

So, I go back to an old-school trick:

- close the window with tabs you want to reload
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

It will reopen closed windows with all the tabs you want to reload.

Comment: Duplicate for: https://superuser.com/a/295362/53983

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the [Reload all tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reload-all-tabs/midkcinmplflbiflboepnahkboeonkam?hl=en-GB) chrome extension :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Most reload tab utility hogs my system and freezes my browsers as they try to reload everything at the same time. As a solution I introduced a delay between my reloads, not only that the delays increases based on number of tabs you have opened.

- [Code](https://github.com/ishandutta2007/mass-reload-tabs-extension)
- [Chrome extension](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/mass-reload-tabs-%E2%88%92-reload/acdllffcofplaibglnoggdlpciplfoed)
- [Edge extension](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/ncikcanpodoeekdggonpomoplgkchdnp)